# MS Access VBA / Formatting emails w/ MS Word template vs. using code

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, formatting, mailmerge

I'd like to use an MS Word template to format emails for a mail merge. I currently use MS Access / VBA / MS Outlook to generate emails, but all of the formatting I'm looking for I hardcode (e.g. {b}, {i}, {u}, {br /}, etc.) Is there a way to use an existing MS Word template to create the body of my email, and allow me to enter data in merge fields.

I don't know how to integrate an MS Word template into my VBA code to generate emails in MS Outlook.

Comment: An easier way is to use Outlook mail templates (.oft): `Set oItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("path\to\mytemplate.oft")`

Comment: ^ this. I was about to post the same. See the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate

Comment: I could still use some direction as to how to use the MS Outlook template in a mail merge via VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a draft email with placeholders as a template on the disk. When required, you can create a new item based on the Outlook template item and then replace placeholders in the message body with the data required. Use the `HTMLBody` property of Outlook items which represents the message body.

Read more about that in the article which I wrote for the technical blog - [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also save a html page/template in a richtext memo field and use the replace() function to fill your merge fields, no ms word needed.

Comment: What if I need to include a table or a hyperlink in the body of the email? I don't think the RichText format will support either of those.